# GTM Tag Firing - Event Not Recorded in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up AdWords/Analytics event tracking on this [page](http://edennisacinc.com/contact-us/). I've previewed and debugged a click tracker for the Submit button (trigger=click ID) successfully.

However once I publish the tag, and test it live, no event data is passed through to GA. I've verified that I'm using the correct GA ID in the tag. This template has an injected GA script right before the GTM tag. Does the GTM tag need to precede the GA script in order to pass the data along?

Comment: How are you verifying that no event data is passed to GA? Are you checking with GA Debugger or in the dev console? Have you waited at least 24 hours for the data to be processed into your reports? I can see an event hit going to property ID UA-80003620-1.

Comment: Hi the event is working and the data is sending properly, but the implementation has a big issue, the GTM is inside a DIV and some tag will not work at all.

Try to move the GTM Main Snippet just after the opening of the body, if you cant try to add it on the header but without the noScript section.

Regarding the event, are you 100% sure that is not working?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance gents, works like a charm now!!

Comment: how did you solve it @rokenbk97? please share your solution